# How to play hiksource video use opencv

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, opencv3.0

I use Gstreamer to get a stream from Hiksource,

```
gst-launch-0.10 hiksource location=/home/tmp/a.mp4 ! typefind ! hikdecoder ! capsfilter  ! ffmpegcolorspace ! audovideosink
```

Then I want to play the video use Opencv, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Do you want to play the video, or to do something (what?) with OpenCV? The question needs more details in this part.

Comment: just play it, I'm new hand...

Comment: for the video is Hik format, it cannot be play in ordinary way,so I use gst-launch to get the pipeline about the video.Then I want to use Opencv to help me to play the pipe firstly,but I don't know how. Do something else is next step.